# Constrain UINavigationView's size to that of its currently presented controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I'm having some trouble figuring out the actual structure of a UINavigationController. I would like to constrain it so that its view matches the preferred size of the top controller's view.

Something like:

```
navController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navController.topViewController?.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Gives me the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000472e00 "UILayoutContainerView:0x7f9f01d14310.top">
and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x608000270ac0 "UIView:0x7f9f01d182b0.top">
because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors
reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Apparently the top controller's view is in a different hierarchy. How is that possible? How can I achieve my goal of creating a non-full screen UINavigationController? Please don't suggest a hack like making the bottom half of the child controller blank or something.

Comment: How are you setting `navController.topViewController?.view.heightAnchor`?

Comment: It's child views determine its height.

Comment: So... the root view controller of your nav controller has a subview with a `.height` constraint? Where / how is that height constraint being set?

Comment: Since you don't own the nav controller's view, it seems unwise to try to change its size, but I agree, the message doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve my goal of creating a non-full screen UINavigationController?

Two easy ways:

- Present the navigation controller as a presented view controller and customize the presentation. (A popover is an example, by the way: the navigation controller *does* resize itself to its child's preferred size.)
- Make a parent view controller, and make the navigation controller its child.

In both approaches, the navigation controller's view size is entirely up to you.